# How to pass signal to another process?

Tags: c, linux

By looking at the syntax of signal I can see that it does not give flexibility of passing signal to another pid (pid_t). a process can only either ignore, do default or customise action on itself. what are the possible ways we can pass signals to another process ? ( I am not talking about pthreads).

Comment: Does `man kill` answer your question?

Comment: also to add I am ruling out the option of using shell command to pass signal or making use of exec for killing process or sending signal

Comment: @SergeyA I just mention that in my above comment, not looking for kill command

Answer (score 5):

You want the [kill(2) system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) (not the `kill` shell command):

> ```
> #include <sys/types.h>
> #include <signal.h>
>
> int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
> ```
>
> The `kill()` system call can be used to send any signal to any process
>   group or process.
>
> If pid is positive, then signal sig is sent to the process with the ID
>   specified by pid.
>
> If pid equals 0, then sig is sent to every process in the process
>   group of the calling process.
>
> If pid equals -1, then sig is sent to every process for which the
>   calling process has permission to send signals, except for process 1
>   (init), but see below.
>
> If pid is less than -1, then sig is sent to every process in the
>   process group whose ID is -pid.
>
> If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still
>   performed; this can be used to check for the existence of a process ID
>   or process group ID.

Running `man kill` will give you kill(1), which is the shell command.  To get the man page for the system call, you run `man 2 kill`.